# Pybind11: How to access the property method of a python object in the C++?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

In the following code, I want to access the property method of a python object by pybind11 (v2.4.3), but get `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. If I comment out the `@property` decorator, the code is OK. Beside, how do I call the `attr.setter` method in the C++ binding code?

Python code:

```
class Example:
  def __init__(self):
    self._attr = "hello world"
  
  # If I comment out the @property, everything is OK.
  @property
  def attr(self):
    return self._attr
  
  # @attr.setter
  # def attr(self, value):
  #   self._attr = value
```

C++ code:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

void print_attr(const py::object &obj) {
  std::cout << obj.attr("attr")() << std::endl;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("print_attr", &print_attr);
}
```

Python test code:

```
import example

obj = Example()
example.print_attr(obj)
```

Comment: What happens when you do `obj.attr("attr")` without the second set of parens?

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't _call_ what you get from `obj.attr("attr")`. Try to cast it to `std::string` instead with `obj.attr("attr").cast<std::string>()`